# Restrict access to website from its ip address.

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ip

Is there any solution to restrict aite access from its ip address like my website ip address is 22.22.22.22. It should open when user access by domain name only www.mydomain.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(4yourprice\.com|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.4yourprice.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Its not working. showing internal server error 500 .

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part, fixed it now. Try again.

Comment: this great bro thanks alot.. But help me with this one too if anyone type mydomain.com it should also go to www.mydomain.com

Comment: Anubhava actually domain contains numeric letter also its 4yourprice.com. when we type it, redirects to yourprice.com

Comment: Check edited rule and make sure to use a new browser to test it.