# stop access to website by IP address

Tags: java, apache, weblogic-10.x

Please let me know if i request using 127.0.0.1/xyz then i should redirect to different site using apache reqwrite condition rules.. Can you please shed your info on this? My question is similar to this [Restrict access to website from its ip address.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192822/restrict-access-to-website-from-its-ip-address?rq=1)

Comment: The HTTP Host header should tell you the name that the user used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below rule in your Virtual Host configuration.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xyz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http:/­/url.todifferentsite.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Dear @Slash This worked for me locally, however i need to import this on production.  I tried this it is working for me now... Now if i am hitting from the browser with 127.0.0.1/xyz i am redirected to localhost/xyz .... thanks alot this is life saviour resolution....<VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127\.0\.0\.1$
 RewriteRule ^ http://localhost/xyz [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>   But i hope adding this will not effect to the users who are browsing the site by URL correct?.... Thanks alot.. once again ..Cheers...

Comment: That's correct. This rule will only redirect when http://127.0.0.1/xyz is aceessed. You're Welcome! Glad that it is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

To block specific users having IP address `w.x.y.z` , you can configure your `.htaccess` file.
Read more about `.htaccess` here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess

```
order allow,deny
deny from w.x.y.z
allow from all
```

Comment: Its not denying a user based on their IP address, I require users should not browse the site by IP address of the server. Eg: example.com browsing is fine but he should not browse by example.com host Ip address

Comment: this requirement makes no sense for me - maybe you can have a look at the host field in the http header

Comment: @akshay your suggestion is to block the users from IP address.

Comment: yes i do not need to block the users based on their IP address, i need user not to access my website using webserver hosted IP address, only he needs to access by domain name not from IP

Answer (score 0):

As of i have personally used this logic from front end there are two ways:

if you wanted to do it using JavaScript

```
if(window.location.host == "10.20.29.162:8080")
{
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
}
```

above logic will check for the host name for example your ip address is "10.20.29.162:8080" then your page will be moved to "http://example.com/new_url" URL

it can be done with the metatag as well

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://example.com/new_url">
```

You just need to check from the backed if host is IP put this meta tag at the header.

there might be some more way to handle it from the backend.

hope this helps

Comment: can't this be done using http rewrite condition in apache RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(4yourprice\.com|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.4yourprice.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]...  i am struggling to make this work through apache httpd.conf file

Comment: Dear Naveen Kumar thanks for your information, this can be used as a workaround but not optimum solution, because my application do not have any common page so i need to add this condition in 100 pages :-(

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting properly if I browse the site by IP address.

Hope this will help others.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127\.0\.0\.1$
    RewriteRule ^ http://localhost.com/xyz [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```